# Vue Component Button is not being disabled dynamically

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component `command-button` wrapping a **Vuetify** `v-btn` component.

`command-button` receives a property called `disabled` of type boolean, non-required and false by default.

`command-button` is being used inside another component called `toolbar` where inside a `v-for` loop I add the `command-button` using a configuration array of `actions` objects passed to `toolbar` as a property.

```
<command-button
  v-for="(action, index) in actions"
  :key="index"
  :label="action.label"
  :disabled="action.disabled"
  @click="action.handler"
></command-button>
```

When I use my `toolbar` component in **my view component** like this:

```
<toolbar :actions="actions"></toolbar>
```

I declare the `actions` of the `toolbar` in the data of **my view component**, as follows:

```
data() {
  return {
    ...        
    actions: [
      {
        label: "Delete",
        handler: this.onDelete,
        disabled: this.disable // This can be a computed or a data element
      },
      {
          label: "Add",
          handler: this.onAdd
      }
    ],
    ...
  },
```

The issue is that the `command-button` is not being disabled dynamically, no matter if I use a `computed` or a member in `data`. It only works if I use the literal `true` inside the `actions` configuration object. Making some debugging, the value received inside `toolbar` for the `disabled` attribute of `actions` element is `undefined`.

Comment: Are you getting `label` attribute?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are redered with the label without issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a computed property in your `data` object as it won't be defined when the instance is created. You could add a watcher on `this.disable` and update the value of `actions[0].disabled` when it changes.

Comment: I resolved with an event instead a watcher. But indeed the fact of I cannot use computed or other data members as values for data members, clarified me a lot... Thanks!